# Need extract key regex

Tags: regex, key

I have the key, format `"H10AX-EAXR9-F2DGA"`, 
me need extract key by pattern regex. So how to do it?
Thanks all!

Hello all. 
I have the key, format `"H10AX-EAXR9-F2DGA"`, 
me need extract key by pattern regex. So how to do it?
Thanks all!

Comment: its very unclear what you are asking

Comment: Regex: (.*)-(.*)-(.*) not working(

Comment: What regex engine/language are you using? Could you give more context to your question?

Comment: Not engine. simply sublime text editor...

Comment: @user2429282 its not working because you need to escape the hiphens like this `(.*)\-(.*)\-(.*)`

Answer (score 0):

```
/(\w{5}\-\w{5}\-\w{5})/
```

this will get you values in the format of `H10AX-EAXR9-F2DGA`

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/cA2nS2

In sublime text 2, you can find and replace like this

[image]

original text

[image]

gets replaced to

[image]

Comment: another question, how to get this text: This is text to extractH10AX-EAXR9-F2DGA, need only "This is text to extract".

Comment: @user2429282 use `(.*)(\w{5}\-\w{5}\-\w{5})` and you will get the value of "This is text to extract" in \1 or $1 whatever your language supports , demo here : http://regex101.com/r/nM6wG4

Comment: in this extract me not need key. how do it?

Comment: just remove the parenthesis from the second part, like this : `(.*)\w{5}\-\w{5}\-\w{5}`

Comment: @user2429282 do you want to just search and replace all using regex or what in sublime? in that case what do you want as final output?